# Bash script unable to download source packages from a list

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh, apt-get

I have a list of packages installed on my Ubuntu 16.04. I have a bash script which tries to download their sources one by one in the appropriate directories (created). I am getting an error:

```
Reading package lists...
E: Unable to find a source package for xxxx
~/source
~/sourcexxx
```

My bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read package
do
    #cd /mnt
    mkdir $package
    pushd $package
    apt-get -d -q source $package
    popd
done < ins.txt
```

I don't want to update any system files.
**apt-get -d -q source xxx** works on its own, but not in the script above. What could be the reason?

A part of my ins.txt:

```
adduser
adium-theme-ubuntu
adwaita-icon-theme
alacarte
alsa-base
alsa-utils
amd64-microcode
anacron
apg
app-install-data
app-install-data-partner
apparmor
apparmor-easyprof
```

When I do individually for eg apt-get -d -q source adduser , it works

Comment: Should `while` read from `dpkg-query -f ` or from file `ins.txt`?

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: From ins.txt - which has all my packages listed which I want to download..

Comment: `dpkg-query -f` does not list packages. It is used to specify the output format. What does your `ins.txt` file contain? Why do you actually use `dpkg-query`? Just remove it, and also the pipe character after it.

Comment: @mivk - I get the same Unable to find a source error even after I remove it. The first line is now just: while read package

Comment: Show us (a part of) your ins.txt file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @mivk - updated original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your list, this seems to work fine for me (on Ubuntu 16.04) after removing the `dpkg-query -f |` part :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read package
do
    echo "Package $package"
    mkdir -v $package
    pushd $package
    apt-get -d -q source $package
    popd
done < ins.txt
```

Maybe some packages don't have a source, or your ins.txt file contains invalid packages.

But that question would sure have been better posted on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).